# OpenJMS - Client port number

Tags: client, client-server, jms, port, openjms

With regards to the problem Bart is having in [NAT router blocking JMS messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13455209/nat-router-blocking-jms-messages)
I am trying to find the port number that clients receive openJMS messages on. After searching for ages on the web I can only find information about the server ports, nothing on the client. This is for a tcp connection.

If anyone can point me in the right direction I would be very grateful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the client port number will be different for each new connection. **I could find no evidence that OpenJMS clients use specific port numbers when communicating with servers.** Here are a few explanations.

1. [Port Numbers](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cicsts/v3r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.cics.ts31.doc/dfhtl/topics/dfhtl2d.htm)

   > When a client process first contacts a server process, it may use a
   >   well-known port number to initiate communication. Well-known port
   >   numbers are assigned to particular services throughout the Internet,
   >   by IANA, the Internet Assigned Numbers Authority. The well-known port
   >   numbers are in the range 0 through 1023.
   >
   > Well-known ports are used only to establish communication between
   >   client and server processes. When this has been done, the server
   >   allocates an ephemeral port number for subsequent use. Ephemeral port
   >   numbers are unique port numbers which are assigned dynamically when
   >   processes start communicating. They are released when communication is
   >   complete.
2. [TCP/IP Client (Ephemeral) Ports and Client/Server Application Port Use](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_TCPIPClientEphemeralPortsandClientServerApplicatio.htm)

   > In contrast, servers respond to clients; they do not initiate contact
   >   with them. Thus, the client doesn't need to use a reserved port
   >   number. In fact, this is really an understatement: a server ***shouldn't***
   >   use a well-known or registered port number to send responses back to
   >   clients. The reason is that it is possible for a particular device to
   >   have both client and server software of the same protocol running on
   >   the same machine. If a server received an HTTP request on port 80 of
   >   its machine and sent the reply back to port 80 on the client machine,
   >   it would be sending the reply to the client machine's HTTP ***server***
   >   process (if present) and not the client process that sent the initial
   >   request.
   >
   > To know where to send the reply, the server must know the port number
   >   the client is using. This is supplied by the client as the Source Port
   >   in the request, and then used by the server as the destination port to
   >   send the reply. Client processes don't use well-known or registered
   >   ports. Instead, each client process is assigned a temporary port
   >   number for its use. This is commonly called an ephemeral port number.
3. Similar answer on another question: [How to decide on port number between client and server communication on internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9788636/how-to-decide-on-port-number-between-client-and-server-communication-on-internet):

   > Also, a client can connect to many servers on the same port. When the
   >   clients connect, they will use a random port on there end.
   >
   > Only the server needs to worry about using a free port, and the
   >   clients need to know what this port is else they will not be able to
   >   connect to your server.

Other possible help:

- [How to find number of ephemeral ports in use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10237419/how-to-find-number-of-ephemeral-ports-in-use)